# what is the keyboard shortcut to search for a file in visual code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, editor

I am working on a macbook .I have my repository synced in visual code through sftp and I would like to search or go to a file in the repo.When I do a CMD+P it goes only if the file is recently opened.But is there a way to traverse to a file which is not opened , but exists in the repo ?.

Answer (score 0):

hit the `Command + p` and search through your project files

Comment: When I do a Command+p it searches only through the recent files , it does not search for unopened files in the project ...I would like to traverse to a file which is not opened but exists in my project directory ...

Comment: if you type your file name it helps you to find that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the new process of downloading and indexing the entire repository will help you find those files without having to open them.

You should test it in v1.65:

> Workspace search and find all references will now download and index a
> full copy of the repository by default, rather than defaulting to
> providing partial results as before. There are several settings to
> configure this:
>
> - `remoteHub.indexing.verboseDownloadNotification`: controls whether the download notification is shown as a popup (default) or in the
>   status bar
> - `remoteHub.indexing.maxIndexSize`: controls the size limit of indexes to download - if this is exceeded the download will be
>   cancelled and partial results will be provided. Leave this empty to
>   never download repositories and use partial results always.

- from [v1.65 Release Notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_65.md#remote-repositories)