# VScode Search not working properly on remote machine

Tags: visual-studio-code

Not sure if this is related but after reseting my windows, search on remote machine doesn't work that well, it looks like indexing issue. because search seems to work only on files that were previously opened manualy.

Majority of topics advise to Reaload the Window which i did but issue is still present. can you kindly advise how to reindex my files ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71301920/836330 - that might help you.